# SQL Query syntax issues when using variable

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, syntax

SQL query `"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON name_$DBname.* TO 'name_$DBname'@'localhost'"`

Output for this:

```
Access denied for user 'name'@'localhost' to database 'name_posmechanics'
```

when written like below - it outputs the variable correctly but..

SQL query `"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON name_$DBname.* TO '. 'name_$DBname'@'localhost'. "`

**error for syntax**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name_posmechanics'@'localhost'.' at line 1
```

It shows that when written the way it wants to be, it will ignore my variable, but it did show correctly **'name_posmechanics'@'localhost'** when the syntax error is present and shows **'name'@'localhost'** whith no syntax errors? **why would the variable work referring to the db name but not when refering to the User**

I understand there is a issue with permissions at the moment, however I would like to get the syntax error corrected first and then move on the the next issue.

here is the complete code

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'pos_URL__db', 'init' ));   //This will trigger everytime the page is refreshed but only apply if all conditions are met
class pos_URL__db {

public static function init() {
        $POS__sys_db = __CLASS__;
        new $POS__sys_db;
    }
    
public function __construct()
{
add_action('init', array($this, 'pos__URL_DB'));
}

public function pos__URL_DB()
{

//--------to access the order objects----start-----
$orders = wc_get_orders(array(
    'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
    'return' => 'ids',
));
//add the id of the custom meta field that lies in the order
$meta_data = array();
foreach ($orders as $order_id) {
  $meta_data[$order_id] = get_post_meta($order_id, '_engx_text_field_id', true); //get the field value entered by the vendor on checkout
}
//--------to access the order objects-----end-----
        
        
if( isset($meta_data[$order_id]) ) { //is the custom field set

    //dependencies
    $servername = "localhost"; // always the same "localhost"
    //$username   = $meta_data[$order_id];  //get name of field unique to each user saved from checkout process
    $username   = "name";  //get name of field unique to each user saved from checkout process
    //$password   = "testing22"; //passcode for database
    $password   = 'TestIngTT'; //passcode for database
    $DBname     = $meta_data[$order_id]; //get name of field unique to each user saved from checkout process

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    

    //mysql_connect('localhost','user',password);
    //mysql_query("CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';");
    //mysql_query("GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'username'@'localhost'");
    
    // Create User
    //$sql = "CREATE DATABASE  . $DBname . ";  //Name of NEW Database replace "myDB" with the POS-URL custom field meta value from checkout
    //$sql = "CREATE DATABASE testDB";  //Name of NEW Database replace "myDB" with the POS-URL custom field meta value from checkout
    
    $sqlcommands = array(
                "CREATE DATABASE name_$DBname",
                "CREATE USER 'name_$DBname'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'TestIngTT!'",
               //"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO name_$DBname",
                "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON name_$DBname.* TO 'garagepo_$DBname'@'localhost'",
               //"GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'username'@'localhost'"
            );
        
        foreach ($sqlcommands as $sql)
    {
        // Create database
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          echo "Database created successfully";  //comment when not needed
        } else {
          echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($conn);  //comment when not needed
        } 
    }

    
    mysqli_close($conn);
    
    }
}//end pos__URL_DB

    

}//end Class pos_URL__db
```

Comment: remove the dot after  single quote after `TO`

Comment: for godsake, use the curly brackets for string interpolation.